# Is there a way to change the clicked color of the Chip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the clicked color of a Chip component, without changing my `theme.js`.

I have tried using the `classes` override, with the colors that I need, but its still changing it to the primary/secondary colors. I found this part in the [implementation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Chip/Chip.js)

```
[...]
 /* Styles applied to the root element if `onClick` and `color="primary"` is defined or `clickable={true}`. */
    clickableColorPrimary: {
      '&:hover, &:focus': {
        backgroundColor: emphasize(theme.palette.primary.main, 0.08),
      },
    },
/* Styles applied to the root element if `onClick` and `color="secondary"` is defined or `clickable={true}`. */
clickableColorSecondary: {
      '&:hover, &:focus': {
        backgroundColor: emphasize(theme.palette.secondary.main, 0.08),
      },
    },
[...]
```

and I was wondering if there was a way to overide this...

My attempt with the `classes` override looks like this,

```
<Chip
    classes={{
        ColorSecondary: '#00d799',
        ColorPrimary: '#ffb34b',
    }}
    color={!clicked ? 'primary' : 'secondary'}
    size="small"
    label={`${clicked ? 'Copied!' : 'Copy'}`}
    onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}
/>
```

but it didn't help.

edit:

I've updated my code according to Fred A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59678123/11538131):

```
<Chip
    classes={{
        colorPrimary: classes.overrideColorPrimary,
        colorSecondary: classes.overrideColorSecondary,
    }}
    color={!clicked ? 'primary' : 'secondary'}
    size="small"
    label={`${clicked ? 'Copied!' : 'Copy'}`}
    onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}
/>
```

using the `classes` prop:

```
[...]
overrideColorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffb34b',
},
overrideColorSecondary: {
    backgroundColor: '#00d799',
},
[...]
```

But I'm still having issues when the Chip is focused or hovered, where it defaults to the `theme.js` colors.
after clicking the Chip, this property shows up:

```
.MuiChip-clickableColorPrimary:hover, .MuiChip-clickableColorPrimary:focus {
    background-color: rgb(137, 137, 138);
}
```

when inspecting the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classes` props is used to Override or extend the styles applied to the component. See [CSS API](https://material-ui.com/api/chip/#css) below for more details.

OR

You can override CSS attributes by adding a new class or you can pass the CSS attributes to the `style` props.

Please check my [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6jp56?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) example.

Comment: I can change the base color, but its when its `&focus` or `&hover` that it seems to use the original colors. 

It happens when I click it.

Comment: I have updated the code in the code sandbox. Please check that once

`chip: {
    backgroundColor: "#59d8ef",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#2196f3",
      cursor: "pointer"
    }
  }`

Comment: Changing the `"&:hover": { backgroundColor: "#2196f3")` property fixed it for me, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use classes property like that. The ColorSecondary and ColorPrimary are the classes located within the Chip component which you can access using the classes property, therefore to override it, you need to pass your own self defined classes to it.

```
/* Define the styling to pass into the classes */
const styles = theme => ({
    overrideColorPrimary: { /* styling in here */ },
    overrideColorSecondary: { /* styling in here */ }
});

/* Inside the component function */
const { classes } = props

/* Pass it to the classes like that */
<Chip
    classes={{
            ColorPrimary: classes.overrideColorPrimary
            ColorSecondary: classes.overrideColorSecondary
        }}
    color={!clicked ? 'primary' : 'secondary'}
    size="small"
    label={`${clicked ? 'Copied!' : 'Copy'}`}
    onClick={() => setClicked(!clicked)}
/>
```

This way, the MUI will use your defined styles to the MUI defined classes.

Comment: what would the property be called in the styling?

I've tried `backgroundColor`, and `colorPrimary` \ `colorSecondary`


edit: my bad, the property names inside the `classes` attribute need to be `camelCase`

However, this still didn't really fix it, it still defaults to the original `theme.js` colors

Comment: My way of doing this, is to inspect the class that is responsible for the respective styling, and i would try to modify it on the inspector. If it works, then i would override that responsible class in the classes property of Chip. If it doesn't work, then i would inspect on the target class again, to see if my defined class is there. If its indeed there but it did not change, then adding !important on the style usually would fix it.